# Moving local SVN to a SVN server with Tortoise

Tags: svn, repository

I have created a **SVN** repository with **Tortoise** in my PC to practice with the structure so now I have a repository called `svn_repos` with its internal structure, and a copy of it.

Now I want to move the repository to a server, but I cannot find any command rightclicking on the repository.

I have been reading documentation and this should be anywhere but I cannot find it. Any help would be welcomed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TortoiseSVN is an SVN client. Though it allows you to create repositories, it does not provide any other kind of administration facilities. You have to copy the repo to your server ( and setup serving, authentication ) etc. yourself and TortoiseSVN cannot help you here.